# Updating to Swift 3.0: Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal

Tags: ios, swift3

Im updating my codebase to Swift 3.0, and I cannot figure out how to fix the error I am generating when migrating: "Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal".  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
typealias JSONDictionary = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

func infoDict() -> JSONDictionary {
    return ["users" :
        //the following line generates the error "Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal"
        ["add" : Array(self.addUserIDs), "del" : Array(self.removeUserIDs)],
            "groups" :
                ["add" : Array(self.addCircleIDs), "del" : Array(self.removeCircleIDs)],
            "friends" : friends,
            "type" : 1
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AnyObject` has been changed to `Any` in Swift 3

```
typealias JSONDictionary = Dictionary<String, Any>
```